# ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to TextView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, casting

I am getting a cast error which makes no sense. I've seen other questions with the same title, but note that this question scope is different.

Main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MainFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.test.ui.main.MainFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
package com.example.test.ui.main

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.test.R

class MainFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message_value).setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        (view as TextView).text = "Hello World"
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }
}
```

The above code is the only one in the project, this is all of it.
The crash happens in the fragment's **onClick** callback. I can't understand why such cast error, since the view that the onClick should receive should be the TextView. It has a unique ID, and there is the only view with a click listener. I've tried rebuild, clean, etc., yet crashes anyway.

Next the error stack trace:

```
2021-03-30 13:56:55.632 1311-1311/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 1311
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.test.ui.main.MainFragment.onClick(MainFragment.kt:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7192)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27592)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Comment: check your import file or show use and also remove this line  (view as TextView).text = "Hello World"

Comment: `v` i s not `view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    (v as TextView).text = "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: omg!!! Thank you, what a silly mistake!!! I will accept the answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me, it told me to wait 10 minutes, probably because I have a low rep.

Comment: ViewBinding can save you from this kind of silly mistake.